# CSS min-width property is not functioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have following problem:
I have div containing other elements and I try to make its width dependent from the content. I also restrict maximum width of this div. I use `min-width` and `max-width` in CSS, but it seems that `min-width` is not working. The width of div is always the `max-width` value, no matter what the content is.

**Example:**

I'd like to have the white div (that is main div, I was talking about) strictly around the form that is in it, without empty spaces on the left and right side. I gave the form style `max-width:500px` to show that even if content is small, the main div stays the same.

**HTML**

```
<div class="gInnerBox sInnerBoxMain">
    <form style="max-width:500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">            
        <div id='content'>
                   <!-- CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gInnerBox{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;    

    box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px #000, 5px 5px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px #000, 5px 5px 20px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px #000, 5px 5px 20px #000;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}

.sInnerBoxMain{
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 50px;
}
```

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [wstaw.org](http://wstaw.org/m/2011/11/25/ttt.png))</sub>

Comment: For future visitors: The accepted answer is completely correct, but if you're dealing with a flex container you can use `display: inline-flex`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By default, a block-level element will expand to fill as much width as possible. So its width is basically "100%" (sort of) and you're saying a maximum of 1000px, so it's expanding to the maximum of 1000px. The minimum width is still being achieved (it's at least 500px). Try setting `display: inline-block` on the element and see if that helps you out any. This should make it only expand as far as its content while still paying attention to the minimum and maximum widths. You may have to add a breaker `<br />` after to make the rest of your content adapts to it being inline.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But the div is not centered now - it sticks to the left. I tried fixing it with putting it into
`<div style="text-align: center">  <div></div>  </div>`
But is there any better way of centering it? (Parent div with `margin-left` and `margin-right: auto` won't work, because I'd still need min-width and this is my previous problem)

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, the min-width still not working