# min-width doesn't work in the css style

Tags: css

Actually I am too lazy to ask this question since this should be the most basic thing for me. But as I still can't solve it then this is a little thing which is important to me, I can't help it.

Yeah, the min-width is not working for me too (with some treats out there which has similar issue). I have set the inline-style, float left, and overflow hidden or not. But it still doesn't fix it.

```
  <style>
     div {
        width:300px;
        min-width:150px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:yellow;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
     }
  </style>

  <body>

       <div>
           This/is what I want 
           is/everything in this world beautiful to see for me
           a/love is more happiness thing than money 
           text/me to say I miss you too
       </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: I think you should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263543/css-min-width-property-is-not-working

Comment: If width is 300, then min-width 150 is always true. What did you expect?

Comment: The min-width value should be grater than width.

Comment: what exactly do you want the min width to do? since you hardcoded the 300px width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the width of the div to 300px. So this div will always be 300px wide. Change it to 
`max-width:300px;` and it will work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/9vv9mvk1/1/)

And now there is also no need to declare `float`and `inline` you only need:

```
div {
    max-width:300px;
    min-width:150px;
    background:yellow;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 div {
        width:30%;
        min-width:150px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:yellow;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
     }
```

use width in % to make min-width effective otherwise it will only take 300px as set value

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle to prove it that it works? I am just not sure if you have tried it. It doesn't work with me.

Comment: it will be fluid till 150px then stop there

Comment: I vote it up. It takes me a time to see that it works. Thank you.